# :Method => Delete Route Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

This button to the delete path seems to get routed to my friendships#create action somehow:

```
<%= button_to "Unfriend", unfriend_path(@user), :method => :delete, :class => "btn primary", :remote => true %>
```

Routes File:

```
match 'friendships/:id', :to => 'friendships#create', :method => :post, :as => 'friendship_request'
match 'friendships/:id', :to => 'friendships#destroy', :method => :delete, :as => 'unfriend'
```

Here is the server log

```
Started POST "/friendships/45" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-11 19:56:46 -0500
  Processing by FriendshipsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"UicOeyAtNuQTd1nAg8XiUtki7B5iOiDtPgJ/Wu8Z+i0=", "_"=>"", "method"=>:post, "id"=>"45"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 101 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 45 LIMIT 1
  Friendship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 101 AND "friendships"."friend_id" = 45 LIMIT 1
  Friendship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 45 AND "friendships"."friend_id" = 101 LIMIT 1
Rendered users/_invited.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered friendships/create.js.erb (1.5ms)
```

Here is the rendered HTML (with the hidden method delete form)

```
<form method="post" action="/friendships/45" data-remote="true" class="button_to"><div><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete"><input action="destroy" class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Unfriend"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="UicOeyAtNuQTd1nAg8XiUtki7B5iOiDtPgJ/Wu8Z+i0="></div></form>
```

Comment: So I tried switching the order of those routes in the route file...and now it calls the destroy action just fine. Something's screwy there, but I'm not sure how to fix it so that both named routes work.

Answer (score 0):

The delete is not a supported option for button_to, only post and get are. (Source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

Make sure that there is a hidden field in the generated form named _method with a value of delete.

If one isn't being generated, you can insert it on the fly using Javascript.

Comment: Well the generated html has this <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete"> in it already. I've been monkeying around with this quite a bit now and changing it to a resource helps with the delete route, but doesn't help with my create route.